# Trying to chose a random image to load in a game

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to learn python and my book has me basically do space invaders
But I wanted to make the alien fleet more interesing by loading a variety of alien ships

Maybe s/o can help me, because I am hitting a wall

Is there a way to combine the image load and the random choice?

**Original Code:**

```
import pygame
import random
from pygame.sprite import Sprite

class Alien(Sprite):
    '''Represents a single alien in the fleet'''

    def __init__(self, ai_game):
        '''Initialize the alien and set its starting position'''
        super().__init__()
        self.screen = ai_game.screen

        # Load the alien image and set its rect attribute
        self.image = pygame.image.load('_IMGS/alien.png')
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

        # Startt each new alien near the top left of the screen
        self.rect.x = self.rect.width
        self.rect.y = self.rect.height

        # Store the alien's exact horizontal position
        self.x = float(self.rect.x)
```

**What I tried**

```
import pygame
import random
from pygame.sprite import Sprite

class Alien(Sprite):
    '''Represents a single alien in the fleet'''

    def __init__(self, ai_game):
        '''Initialize the alien and set its starting position'''
        super().__init__()
        self.screen = ai_game.screen

        # Load the alien image and set its rect attribute
        rnd_alien = random.choice('_IMGS/alien.png', '_IMGS/alien2.png')
        self.image = rnd_alien
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

        # Startt each new alien near the top left of the screen
        self.rect.x = self.rect.width
        self.rect.y = self.rect.height

        # Store the alien's exact horizontal position
        self.x = float(self.rect.x)
```

**Traceback:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Dropbox\PYTHON\Alien_Invaders\alien_invasion.py", line 99, in <module>
    ai.run_game()
  File "D:\Dropbox\PYTHON\Alien_Invaders\alien_invasion.py", line 35, in run_game
    self._create_fleet()
  File "D:\Dropbox\PYTHON\Alien_Invaders\alien_invasion.py", line 82, in _create_fleet
    alien = Alien(self)
  File "D:\Dropbox\PYTHON\Alien_Invaders\alien.py", line 14, in __init__
    self.image = rnd_alien
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'rnd_alien' referenced before assignment
```

Comment: New code never calls `pygame.image.load`.

Comment: @ScottHunter Yeah I know, I tried that too, but couldn't work out how to combine the two :/

Comment: You forgot the wrap the image names in [] to make it an array. `random.choice(['_IMGS/alien.png', '_IMGS/alien2.png'])`

Comment: @RickardElimää
OMG I am an idiot. THANK YOU

            rnd_alien = random.choice(['_IMGS/alien.png', '_IMGS/alien2.png'])
        self.image = pygame.image.load(rnd_alien)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()    

this actually worked (in a way) now it flickers - but that gave me an idea to add some kind of glowing animation so it's a happy little accident :D